# how do i get all document keys of user in firestore(in Java/android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

How can I get all document keys of USER in Java by single dataSnapshot..... I manage to get keys using for loop...for Example.......

```
  db.collection("USER").get().addOnCompleteListener(
   new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){


  @Override
  public void OnComplet(Task<QuerySnapshot> task){

   if(task.isSuccesfull()){

     for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentID : 
         task.getResult() ) {

        String keys = document.getId();
        allKeys.add(keys);     //adiing to arrayList

    }

         }
```

but i want to get all keys by single dataSnapShot and i know there is definitely a way to this because i manage to get all keys using FireStore in Swift ios Xcode ....if you know Swift than below example will give you a good idea

```
     Firestore.forestore().collection("USER").getDocument(
        completion : {   (queries , Error)    in

          queries?.documents.map({ (keySnapshot) -> Any in 

            print("\(keySnapshot.documentID)")


         return (Any ).self
          })


          }

         )
```